# Why am I getting the Apache2 welcome page instead of the laravel page?

Tags: laravel, apache, vagrant, homestead

I installed laravel via homestead, but when I go to localhost I get the apache2 welcome/success screen. I can't get the Laravel welcome page to load up.

I ran vagrant up on the homestead box but there were no laravel files. So I installed it using `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel app`.

Now when I go to `localhost` I get the apache2 welcome screen. If I put an `index.html` in `/vagrant` I can get that to load up by going to `localhost:8000`. But going to the same address without the index file causes a 403.

I've tried all combinations of URLs, /app, /app/app, /app/public, and I've tried changing the URL in the .env.

Weirdly, I can't find this apache welcome file on the server. The page itself says "You should replace this file (located at /var/www/html/index.html)" If I SSH in and go to that folder, there is an nginx welcome html page there, but no apache one.

If I go to file:///var/www/html/ in the browser, I see the index.html of the apache welcome page. If I go to file:///var/ I see a few different folders there than I do by SSHing into the vagrant box. I don't understand why.

How can I get the Laravel welcome page to appear?

edits:

http://localhost:8000/public returns "No input file specified"

Sites part of homestead.yaml

```
sites:
-
    map: homestead.test
    to: /home/w/work/qs/app/public
```

/etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       qs      qs
192.168.10.10   homestead.test
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
#### HOMESTEAD-SITES-BEGIN
# 127.0.0.1     homestead.test
#### HOMESTEAD-SITES-END
```

Comment: try `localhost:8000/public` what is the output?

Comment: Are you following this? https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/homestead

Comment: Yeah I used the "Per Project Installation" from that page. localhost:8000/public returns "No Input file specified"

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation,

```
you will still need to add an  /etc/hosts file entry for homestead.test or the domain of your choice if you are not using automatic
```

Add domain entry in your `/etc/hosts` file like:

```
192.168.10.10  homestead.test
```

And try brows http://homestead.test from browser

***Make sure the IP address listed is the one set in your Homestead.yaml***

**Edited:**
It seems you may running some commands out of the root directory of the project.

Here is the very short video to verify your steps.

https://youtu.be/a9jtoXXp5ao

All the best!

Comment: I added it, but it can't find anything at that address.

Comment: Have you check this? `Make sure the IP address listed is the one set in your Homestead.yaml`

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's right, but it still doesn't work. However, if I go directly to 192.168.10.10/app/public, it does appear!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195375/discussion-between-vikash-pathak-and-user43107).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add hosts entries for each site and the mappings to your Homestead.yaml:

/etc/hosts:

```
192.168.10.10    homestead.test
```

~/Homestead/Homestead.yaml:

```
sites:
    - map: homestead.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/my-project/public
```

Then still under `~/Homestead`, run `vagrant up --provision`.